# how to import npm module to many js files

Tags: javascript, html, npm, webpack, import

I have a project with an Index.js file, an Index.html file, and a folder called files that contains many JavaScript files. My problem is that I need to import the module that I use in each of these files.

What I tried is importing an npm package. I successfully installed the package, and then I added the following line to my index.js file:
`import * as name from 'moudleName';`

So far, the import statement doesn't work because I get an error that says "I can't import outside a module". To resolve this issue, I tried using webpack:
[image]

And it seems to work - webpack creates a bundle.js file. In my HTML file, I can simply include the following script tag:

[image]

I'm currently facing a problem where I need to use "import * as name..." for all of my JS files that are located in the files folder. I'm wondering how I can achieve this. Do I need to create multiple entry points and then import each output to my HTML file? Or is there a way to make this import inheritance-based on the index.js file that already has that import?

Im really new to this, so ill be happy to get steps what exactly i need to do and where.
thanks!

Comment: It's unclear to me how the title of your question matches the body. The question you ask in the body is valid but too basic. It would require a very long explanation. I think you'd be better off carefully reading about core concepts: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/. Webpack isn't necessarily intuitive, so you aren't deficient if it takes multiple readings to begin to understand basic principles. It took me about a year of working with it to really understand how to use it effectively.

Comment: @JDB Well I guess it is indeed a bit complicated. However, the solution was straightforward; I just needed to import or require the files that I wanted to bundle in the index.js. No need for more entries etc, thats it.